# C1FlexGrid - Change "Highlight" behavior for a range of cells

Tags: vb.net, c1flexgrid

**My scenario:**

I have a C1FlexGrid with Column and Row headers. Additionally, the first row of the C1FlexGrid is a boolean row (checkboxes). Based on the state of these checkboxes, the desired effect is a disabling of the cells for that column. The difficulty is that, due to the first row being a boolean data type that must not be disabled, using the .Cols(index).AllowEditing property is not an option. I have already successfully implemented a work-around using the BeforeEdit event handler, to prohibit changes to the cells in the column, along with a CellStyle to grey-out the cells when disabled.

```vb
Private Sub C1FlexGrid1_BeforeEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.RowColEventArgs) Handles C1FlexGrid1.BeforeEdit
    If e.Row > 1 And Me.C1FlexGrid1.Item(1, e.Col) = False Then e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub C1FlexGrid1_AfterEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.RowColEventArgs) Handles C1FlexGrid1.AfterEdit
    If e.Row = 1 And Me.C1FlexGrid1.Item(1, e.Col) = False Then
        Call FormatColAsDisabled(e.Col)
    ElseIf e.Row = 1 And Me.C1FlexGrid1.Item(1, e.Col) = True Then
        Call FormatColAsEnabled(e.Col)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FormatColAsDisabled(ByVal col As Integer)
    Dim color As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.CellStyle
    color = Me.C1FlexGrid1.Styles.Add("Gray")
    color.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Gray

    For row As Integer = 2 To Me.C1FlexGrid1.Rows.Count - 1
        Me.C1FlexGrid1.SetCellStyle(row, col, color)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FormatColAsEnabled(ByVal col As Integer)
    For row As Integer = 2 To Me.C1FlexGrid1.Rows.Count - 1
        Me.C1FlexGrid1.SetCellStyle(row, col, Me.C1FlexGrid1.Styles("Normal"))
    Next
End Sub
```

**My Question**

Is there a way to modify the "Highlight" behavior for only these cells, such that the disabled cells do not highlight at all?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid highlighting the disabled cells you can set Cancel EventArgs of BeforeSelChange event to true in case the new selected cell is a disabled one.

```
Private Sub C1FlexGrid1_BeforeSelChange(sender As Object, e As RangeEventArgs) Handles C1FlexGrid1.BeforeSelChange
    If e.NewRange.r1 > 1 And Me.C1FlexGrid1.GetCellCheck(1, e.NewRange.c1) = CheckEnum.Unchecked Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```